# TextField background transparency in Codenameone when graphics background

Tags: java, codenameone

My problem is that i have a Form with a 2 colour background; On top i have a  bg transparent textfield. When it renders in the simulator it looks fine as the TextField is positioned across the point in the background where the colours meet (as per field 2).

But when i click into field 3, the Textfield takes on a solid background column of just one of my background colours, when i expect it to stay transparent.
[image: (]

The background consists of a LayeredLayout which is darker blue colour, and then i have a light blue graphic in the bottom half:

```
class RectangleComponent extends Component {

private int bottomColour;

protected void setBottomColour(int colour) {
    bottomColour = colour;
}

@Override
protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(250, 250);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(bottomColour);
    int[] int_x = new int[] { 0, getWidth(), getWidth(), 0 };
    int[] int_y = new int[] { (int) (getHeight() / 2.5), ((int) (getHeight() / 2.5)) + 150, getHeight(),
            getHeight() };

    g.fillPolygon(int_x, int_y, 4);
}
```

My TextField is:

```
public class TextCustom extends TextField {

public TextCustom(String hint, String controlName, int maxChars) {
    Border border = Border.createCompoundBorder(null, Border.createLineBorder(1, 0xffffff), null, null);
    setName(controlName);
    setUIID("v2_Label11LightPadMarg");
    getAllStyles().setBorder(border);
    setHint(hint);
    getHintLabel().setUIID("v2_Label11LightPadMarg");
    getHintLabel().getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xffffff);
    getHintLabel().getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0);
    getHintLabel().setAlignment(Component.TOP);
    getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0);
    getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xffffff);
    getSelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

    setCursorPosition(0);
    setMaxSize(maxChars);
    setColumns(maxChars);
    getAllStyles().setMarginLeft(20);
    getAllStyles().setMarginRight(20);
}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a problem on the simulator. On the android device it seems fine. Closing.

Comment: It's really hard to create a portable way to edit transparently as the UI in some platforms leaves artifacts in such cases. We try our best but in some case it just falls back to standard colors

Comment: So you're saying you can't guarantee it will work on all devices? I only have a limited set of android and apple devices to test on. If you can't then i'll have to back out the work to build that background and apply a PNG background, through the theme, instead. Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure if PNG will be any better for those devices. It's an issue with the idea of transparency during editing. I don't think you need to go through a rewrite to support edge cases.